# Debugging PhoneGap app on VS2010

Tags: cordova

I am running a sample app written using PhoneGap and jquery on VS2010 and Windows 7 Emulator.

How do I step in the javascript code to debug?

I can't seem to find any thread on debugging or stepping in the codes.

Comment: I know there is console.log which shows up in output pane, but its not good enough. i'm asking if its possible to do stepping in a la .net debugging style and how to do it. thx.

Answer (score 0):

good info with few options on debugging PhoneGap applications in general [Debugging PhoneGap Apps](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494768/Debugging%20PhoneGap%20Apps)

Answer (score 0):

When you run your mobile code on a browser like IE there is options to place break points in the debug mode.